# How to determine which pages are not indexed

Tags: google-search-console

Is there a way to determine which pages of a website are not being indexed by the search engines?

I know Google Webmasters has a sitemap area where it tells you how many urls have been submitted and how many are indexed out of those submitted. However, it doesn't necessarily show which urls aren't being indexed.

Even i am not sure what to tag

Answer (score 0):

Google knows only the URL's that are indexed/crawled .

- The URL which has not linked/display even in one webpage will not be
  crawled.
- The URL blocked by Robots.txt will not be crawled.
- If you removed any url's in webmaster tools, then those url's will not be crawled.

There is no known way to know exactly what URL's are not indexed by Google, however we can assume a list of URL by using the above rules.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! It's easy. Or rather it's easy to see which pages *are* indexed. See Google's [discussion of this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35256?hl=en).

It's as simple as going into your broswer and typing "site:www.yoursite.com". That's it. Everything that they have indexed will be listed.